# how to use axel download manager with proxy?

Tags: command-line, proxy, axel

How to use axel download manager with proxy??

example host: 100.100.100.100 , port:8080, username: admin, password: admin2

Answer (score 2):

I'm using `axel` behind a proxy and I usually set all these environment variables

```
export http_proxy='http://<ip>:<port>'
export all_proxy=$http_proxy
export https_proxy=$http_proxy
export ftp_proxy=$http_proxy
export HTTP_PROXY=$http_proxy
export HTTPS_PROXY=$http_proxy
export FTP_PROXY=$http_proxy
```

I just checked and it seems at least the lowercase version is supported:

```
user@hostname:/tmp$ axel http://www.google.com
Initializing download: http://www.google.com
Unable to connect to server www.google.com:80

user@hostname:/tmp$ export http_proxy='http://127.0.0.1:5865'
user@hostname:/tmp$ axel http://www.google.com
Initializing download: http://www.google.com
Opening output file default.1
Server unsupported, starting from scratch with one connection.
Starting download

[  0%]  .......... .
Connection 0 finished

Downloaded 11.3 Kilobyte in 0 seconds. (37.63 KB/s)
```

I think there should be no problem using basic http authentication in this form, but I cannot check it

```
export http_proxy='http://admin:admin2@100.100.100.100:8080'
```